# is it possible to add whitelist of contract in self mainnet node?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, evm

I am working in a company write games on eth mainnet and maintenance a eth node(geth) not using infura.io.

My boss require me our eth node just can deal with our contract, so is it possible to do it? I search google 'geth contract whitelist' but no any result I want.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's against the operating principle of a public blockchain such as mainnet.

You might want to explore private networks or platforms such as Quorum. They are, by definition, not mainnet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In theory I'd imagine it to be at least partially possible. Modify node to only accept certain transactions in a block and hope you win the block. Hmm?